# How to excute script when receiving a SNMP trap?

Tags: bash, snmp, net-snmp, snmp-trap

I found the parameter `traphandle` in the `snmptrapd.conf` file. I found that I can set it like this

```
traphandle default /usr/sbin/snmptt
```

to ad the info of the trap to a log file in `/var/log/snmptt` directory, but I want to make my own bash script to be executed when a trap is received. If I undertood well, I think I can set it to

```
traphandle default my_script.sh
```

and `my_script.sh` would run when a trap is received, but I don't know how to get the info of the trap in my script.

Answer (score 2):

Please refer to man page of the **snmptrapd.conf**

```
   traphandle OID|default PROGRAM [ARGS ...]
          invokes the specified program (with the given arguments) whenever a notification is received that matches the OID  token.   For
          SNMPv2c  and  SNMPv3 notifications, this token will be compared against the snmpTrapOID value taken from the notification.  For
          SNMPv1 traps, the generic and specific trap values and the enterprise OID will be converted into the equivalent OID  (following
          RFC 2576).

          Typically,  the  OID  token  will be the name (or numeric OID) of a NOTIFICATION-TYPE object, and the specified program will be
          invoked for notifications that match this OID exactly.  However this token also supports a simple form of  wildcard  suffixing.
          By  appending  the  character ´*' to the OID token, the corresponding program will be invoked for any notification based within
          subtree rooted at the specified OID.  For example, an OID token of .1.3.6.1.4.1* would match any enterprise specific  notifica‐
          tion (including the specified OID itself).  An OID token of .1.3.6.1.4.1.* would would work in much the same way, but would not
          match this exact OID - just notifications that lay strictly below this root.  Note that this syntax does not support full regu‐
          lar expressions or wildcards - an OID token of the form oid.*.subids is not valid.

          If the OID field is the token default then the program will be invoked for any notification not matching another (OID specific)
          traphandle entry.

   Details of the notification are fed to the program via its standard input.  Note that this will always use the SNMPv2-style  notifica‐
   tion  format,  with SNMPv1 traps being converted as per RFC 2576, before being passed to the program.  The input format is, if you use
   the default set by the "format execute %B\n%b\n%V\n%v\n", one entry per line:

          HOSTNAME
                 The name of the host that sent the notification, as determined by gethostbyaddr(3).

          ADDRESS
                 The transport address, like
                 "[UDP: [172.16.10.12]:23456->[10.150.0.8]]"

          VARBINDS
                 A list of variable bindings describing the contents of the notification, one per line.  The first token on each line (up
                 until  a  space)  is the OID of the varind, and the remainder of the line is its value.  The format of both of these are
                 controlled by the outputOption directive (or similar configuration).

                 The first OID should always be SNMPv2-MIB::sysUpTime.0, and the second should be SNMPv2-MIB::snmpTrapOID.0.  The remain‐
                 ing  lines  will  contain  the payload varbind list.  For SNMPv1 traps, the final OID will be SNMPv2-MIB::snmpTrapEnter‐
                 prise.0.

          Example:
                 A traptoemail script has been included in the Net-SNMP package that can be used within a traphandle directive:

                 traphandle default /usr/bin/perl /usr/bin/traptoemail -s mysmtp.somewhere.com -f admin@somewhere.com me@somewhere.com
```

Answer (score 0):

```
read host
read ip
var=

while read oid val
do
  if [ "$vars" = "" ]
  then
    vars="$oid = $val"
  else
    vars="$vars, $oid = $val"
  fi
done

echo trap: $1 $host $ip $vars > /tmp/go.out
```

Comment: it works from my test site, the content of my_script.sh
traphandle default my_script.sh

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).